# How to Select MAX(Id) max from Table Where key = some_value in SQL C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I need to select and Get a single unique value from a table where the key has duplicate entries. For instance there is a Transaction ID(Id) and an AccountNumber(AccountNumber) and for each account number there are many entries but I have to get only the Maximum (Transaction ID)(Id) for a particular AccountNumber. I am usnig the following code but gives me multiple rows in the result. Am I doing it right? There is no syntax error in this code . If I remove GROUP BY it gives an error stating no Group BY Statement.

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select MAX(Id), Address, AccountNumber, Date, CustomerName, Debit, Credit, Balance from fianlTable WHERE (AccountNumber='"+textBox4.Text+"') ) GROUP BY Id, Address, AccountNumber, Date, CustomerName, Debit, Credit, Balance", con);
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: You have a *SQL injection* vulnerability in that code. You should immediately stop whatever you are doing right now, and go google for what my previous statement means.

Comment: If you are interested to know about the MAX of a particular Account then you don't need the other field neither the GROUP BY

Comment: @Lucas I know about SQL injections But I am building a test app and is just the beginning of my project I will solve it later and requires not much hassle . Please focus on what I asked.

Comment: You don't need to use `con.Open()` - the dataadapter will take care of that. If you do open the connection, you should close it afterwards. In either case, you should also use `con.Dispose()` to keep everything clean.

Comment: @Andrew good suggestion I didn't know about con.Dispose() thanks.

Comment: @AndrewMorton plz have a look on my statement of code also I didn't understand well how to get maximum value. It gives me multiple values. please suggest an edit.

Comment: @Steve plz have a look on my statement of code also I didn't understand well how to get maximum value. It gives me multiple values. please suggest an edit.

Comment: @MuhammadShahid as I have said in my answer below. If you are interested in just getting the MAX(ID) for a particular account then you get rid of everything and use just a barebone sql.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Not specific to C# but more SQL based, you can select the records for the Account Number - sorted by TransactionId Desc and Limit the results to 1.

This would look like:

```
SELECT Id, Address, AccountNumber, Date, CustomerName, Debit, Credit, Balance from fianlTable WHERE (AccountNumber='"+textBox4.Text+"') ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1
```

BTW Lucas is correct you are risking someone hijacking your code by using the value from the textbox directly in the query :)

Comment: your answer seems quiet a lot helpful but it says incorrect syntax near LIMIT I am using visual studio 2013.

Comment: `LIMIT` is for MySQL (and maybe other DBs). For the T-SQL equivalent, see [TOP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx). Steve's answer is better: it's more robust, will work with more databases, and uses fewer resources.

Comment: And also if using TOP, this answer requires to order the resultset before returning the top 1. Sometime it is difficult to understand how the OP selects an answer as helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested to know just the MAX of a particular ID for a particular AccountNumber then you don't need the other fields neither the GROUP BY

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(.....))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select MAX(Id)
                                        from fianlTable 
                                        WHERE AccountNumber=@num"), con)
{
    int maxValue = 0;
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@num" SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox4.Text;
    object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if(result != null) 
      maxValue = Convert.ToInt32(result);
}
```

So there is no need of all the infrastructure required by the SqlDataAdapter but just an SqlCommand, its text and the call to ExecuteScalar. Notice also that disposable objects like the connection and the command are enclosed by a using statement to ensure proper closing and disposing

There is also something else to say here. I don't know the reason behind this code but I hope that is not to get the next ID to assign in an INSERT command. Using MAX for this scenario is wrong because the value returned cannot be trusted in a multiuser environment

Comment: Your answer is correct but it gives an error ExecuteScalar() has not been initialized. please guide me in this context.

Comment: The SqlCommand cmd is initialized in the using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand....)) Probably you are pointing to the missing connection in the SqlCommand constructor. Answer fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want max(id) then thsi colunmn don't should be in group by

```
"select 
     Id
    , Address
    , AccountNumber
    , Date
    , CustomerName
    , Debit
    , Credit
    , Balance 
from fianlTable 
WHERE id = (select max(id) from fianlTable 
           WHERE  AccountNumber='"+textBox4.Text+"' 
GROUP BY AccountNumber);"
```

Comment: Still no progress gives the same multiple results.